# How to generate a graph for dependency in classic asp web application? (Static Analysis)

Tags: asp-classic, dependencies

I have to clean up an asp classic application that was previously not under revision control. There are a lot of unused files that branch within the application (eg: file.asp, file_old.asp, file_username.asp) and binary files that were created by the application. I want to be able to:

1. Understand dependencies
2. Archive unused files

I thought it would be useful to draw a graph of depedency so I can start to remove unused files and directories. Is there a tool to do so? (If not, that's my next open source project.)

I saw microsoft has a tool that can draw these graphs for ASP.net and C++:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657799.aspx

Comment: I'm also looking for static analysis tools for classic asp (death code, etc)

Comment: This is available in VS.NET 2010 Ultimate edition under Architecture menu. Otherwise I can recommend you NDepend (free trial).

Comment: @Karel, only for asp.net

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something like this once.

I ended up writing a script to dump dependencies in dot language

http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html

and using http://www.graphviz.org/ to generate PDF output